# Use data.getCell().getValue() to compare text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to check all cells in row 2 for all columns. If they contain the text "Alt", I want to hide them. I tried the following function:

```
function hideOldColumns() {   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();   var data = sheet.getDataRange();   var lastColumn = data.getLastColumn()+1;   for(var i=1; i<lastColumn; i++) {
    if(data.getCell(2, i).getValue() = "Alt") {
      sheet.hideColumns(i);
    }   } };
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
13:53:31    Fehler  
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
hideOldColumns  @ Code.gs:7
```

However, if I take a numerical comparison, it's working without an error:

```
for(var i=1; i<lastColumn; i++) {
    if(data.getCell(2, i).getValue() < 1) {
      sheet.hideColumns(i);
    }
  }
```

Could someone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `if(data.getCell(2, i).getValue() = "Alt")` might be `if(data.getCell(2, i).getValue() == "Alt")`, or from `If they contain the text "Alt"`, I guessed that you might want `if(data.getCell(2, i).getValue().includes("Alt"))`.
- When `getValue()` is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high. [Ref (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function hideOldColumns() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0];
  values.forEach((c, j) => {
    if (c.includes("Alt")) { // If you want to check whether the value is "Alt", please use c == "Alt"
      sheet.hideColumns(j + 1);
    }
  });
}
```

- In this modification, first, the values are retrieved from row 2. And, when the value contains "Alt", the column is hidden.
- If you want to check whether the value is "Alt", please modify use `if (c.includes("Alt")) {` to `if (c == "Alt") {`

#### Reference:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: @orschiro Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.